# Sum of Normal R.V. is not Symmetric?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

Consider two standard normal random variable, X and Y.

They both have mean 0, and variance 1. But we don't know their dependency.

Is it possible for X+2Y to be non-symmetric? In another word, is it possible for P(X+2Y>0) = 1/2 to not hold.

I understand if they follow multivariate normal, the sum has to be normal and thus symmetric.

Is it possible to construct non-jointly Gaussians X and Y such that the equality does not hold.

Comment: $P(X+2Y>0) = 1/2$ is not a statement that $X+2Y$ is symmetric. Symmetric means $P(Z\ge z) = P(Z\le-z)$ for all $z$ which implies $P(Z>0) = 1/2$ provided $P(Z=0)=0.$ So your statement is weaker than symmetry for continuous random variables and inconsistent with symmetry for ones that have mass at the origin.

Comment: Denote $\Phi$ be the CDF of standard normal.Then note that $\Phi(X)$ will follows $\text{Uniform}(0,1)$. Set $Y = \Phi^{-1}(0.5 - \Phi(X))$ if $X < 0$ and $Y = X$ otherwise. This should make the distribution of $X + 2Y$ not symmetric about $0$, but the median is still at $0$. You may try other transformation of the uniform.

Comment: Thank you spaceisdarkgreen. I agree with your comments.